# Why is regex failing to match all desired groups

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following string

```
{class:"table table-striped"},c.a.createElement("thead",{class:"thread-dark"},c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"},"Round 1"),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}))),c.a.createElement("tbody",null,c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("td",null,"Parc des Princes",c.a.createElement("br",null),"Paris"),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"right"},"France ",c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/France.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})),c.a.createElement("td",{className:"align-middle",align:"center"},c.a.createElement("a",{href:"/fra-kor"},"4 - 0")),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"left"},c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/Korea.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})," Korea"),c.a.createElement("td",null,"Group A")),c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("td",null,"Roazhon Park",c.a.createElement("br",null),"Rennes"),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"right"},"Germany ",c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/Germany.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})),c.a.createElement("td",{className:"align-middle",align:"center"},c.a.createElement("a",{href:"/deu-chn"},"1 - 0")),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"left"},c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/China.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})," China"),c.a.createElement("td",null,"Group B")),c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("td",null,"Stade Oceane",c.a.createElement("br",null),"Le Havre"),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"right"},"Spain ",c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/Spain.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})),c.a.createElement("td",{className:"align-middle",align:"center"}
```

I am trying to retrieve all characters between 2 identical substrings i.e. all characters between `c.a.createElement("tr"`  and `c.a.createElement("tr"` as a list.

My attempt is to use the following regex pattern:

```
c\.a\.createElement\("tr"(.*?)c\.a\.createElement\("tr"
```

Instead of getting every in between sequence some are being skipped as shown in image:

[image]

In the above you can see the second match 1 group 0 (light blue)  is not followed by a group 1 (green) despite there being a following `c.a.createElement("tr"` (match 2 dark blue).

If it helps the regex is available here: https://regex101.com/r/xzbHBU/1/

I tried various lookarounds e.g.

```
(?<=c\.a\.createElement\("tr")(.*?)(?!c\.a\.createElement\("tr")
```

and adding `re.DOTALL` flag; all of which failed miserably to match as were too restrictive.

Can anyone help me write the appropriate regex to retrieve all groups as I described in my expectations?

Python:

```
import re

s = '{class:"table table-striped"},c.a.createElement("thead",{class:"thread-dark"},c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"},"Round 1"),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}))),c.a.createElement("tbody",null,c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("td",null,"Parc des Princes",c.a.createElement("br",null),"Paris"),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"right"},"France ",c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/France.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})),c.a.createElement("td",{className:"align-middle",align:"center"},c.a.createElement("a",{href:"/fra-kor"},"4 - 0")),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"left"},c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/Korea.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})," Korea"),c.a.createElement("td",null,"Group A")),c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("td",null,"Roazhon Park",c.a.createElement("br",null),"Rennes"),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"right"},"Germany ",c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/Germany.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})),c.a.createElement("td",{className:"align-middle",align:"center"},c.a.createElement("a",{href:"/deu-chn"},"1 - 0")),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"left"},c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/China.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})," China"),c.a.createElement("td",null,"Group B")),c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("td",null,"Stade Oceane",c.a.createElement("br",null),"Le Havre"),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"right"},"Spain ",c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/Spain.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})),c.a.createElement("td",{className:"align-middle",align:"center"}'
p = re.compile(r'c\.a\.createElement\("tr"(.*?),c.a.createElement\("tr"')
matches = p.findall(s)
print(len(matches))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lookahead & lookbehind

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = '{class:"table table-striped"},c.a.createElement("thead",{class:"thread-dark"},c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"},"Round 1"),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}),c.a.createElement("th",{scope:"col"}))),c.a.createElement("tbody",null,c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("td",null,"Parc des Princes",c.a.createElement("br",null),"Paris"),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"right"},"France ",c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/France.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})),c.a.createElement("td",{className:"align-middle",align:"center"},c.a.createElement("a",{href:"/fra-kor"},"4 - 0")),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"left"},c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/Korea.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})," Korea"),c.a.createElement("td",null,"Group A")),c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("td",null,"Roazhon Park",c.a.createElement("br",null),"Rennes"),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"right"},"Germany ",c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/Germany.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})),c.a.createElement("td",{className:"align-middle",align:"center"},c.a.createElement("a",{href:"/deu-chn"},"1 - 0")),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"left"},c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/China.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})," China"),c.a.createElement("td",null,"Group B")),c.a.createElement("tr",null,c.a.createElement("td",null,"Stade Oceane",c.a.createElement("br",null),"Le Havre"),c.a.createElement("td",{align:"right"},"Spain ",c.a.createElement("img",{src:"img/RoundFlags/Spain.png",width:"50",hspace:"20"})),c.a.createElement("td",{className:"align-middle",align:"center"}'
p = re.compile(r'(?<=c\.a\.createElement\("tr")(.*?)(?=,c.a.createElement\("tr")')
matches = p.findall(s)
print(matches)
```

**Output:**

```
3
```